# Analytical closed-form solution to a 2nd order BVP with two derivative BCs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, boundary-value-problem, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

I am looking for a symbolic closed-form solution to the following BVP.

$$\frac{d^2 \phi}{dx^2} = c_1 \left ( e^{c_2(\phi(x)+c_3)} - e^{c_4(\phi(x)+c_3)} \right )$$

wherein $c_1, c_2, c_3$ and $c_4$ are real-valued scalar constants.

The boundary conditions are $\phi'(0) = 0$ & $\phi'(1) = 1$ in the unit domain $(0,1)$

I tried solving this using Mathematica's DSolve function, but was unsuccessful in doing so. Then, I tried solving for a linearised version of the RHS using a Taylor expansion about an operating point $\phi^*$. This worked and produced a symbolic answer.

I do realise that non-linear problems are hard and do not always have a general solution. But in this case, I do know that we have a solution (from theory, and also was able to compute it numerically with a relative error/tolerance of $10^{-7}$).

Furthermore, even though we have a double Neumann BC (flux BC) for this elliptic/BVP problem, we have a unique solution due to the fact that the source term is implicit, i.e. it contains the solution variable $\phi(x)$.

Any help regarding solving this problem in any suitable computer algebra package is highly appreciated.

Comment: It would help you to clean up the constants. For example, there is no reason to keep $a$ and $b$ separate; there is no real reason to keep $RT$ instead of just $T$; etc. That said, why is it so important to try to get an analytical solution?

Comment: That's a bit confusing. My RHS is indeed a function of $\phi(x)$. My RHS contains $j(x)$, which is a non-linear function of $\eta(x)$, which is a linear function of $\phi(x)$ as described in my question.

Comment: Sorry, I caught my mistake (I hadn't read far enough forward to see the definition of $\eta$) and removed my comment. I also don't see much of a reason to separately define $\eta$, incidentally, since it is just a translate of $\phi$...

Comment: In other words, it seems like you could save yourself some pain by writing $\frac{d^2 \phi}{dx^2} = c_1 \left ( e^{c_2(\phi(x)+c_3)} - e^{c_4(\phi(x)+c_3)} \right )$. Anyway, I see no real reason why you should expect a closed form solution.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your pointers. This is a famous problem in the field of electrochemistry. I have only posted a minimum (necessary) description of my full problem here, i.e. the piece most relevant. I need an analytical solution because, I intend to use the expression for the solution at the left boundary, $\phi (0)$ to develop a further set of mathematical expressions needed in my research. The problem, in the simplified way that you have written looks innocous enough :). Is finding an analytical solution out of question ?

Comment: Just because you can find a numerical solution doesn't mean a closed form analytic solution should exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try the substitution,
$$\phi = ln z$$
$$\phi_x = z^{-1}z_x$$
$$\phi_{xx}=-z^{-2}(z_x)^2 + z^{-1}z_{xx}$$

Then,
$$-z^{-2}(z_x)^2 + z^{-1}z_{xx}=A_1z^{b_1}+A_2z^{b_2}$$
$$z_{xx}-z^{-1}(z_x)^2=A_1z^{b_3}+A_2z^{b_4}$$

Let $w(z)=(z_x)^2$, 
$$w_zz_x = 2z_xz_{xx}.$$
Then,
$$\frac{1}{2}w_z-z^{-1}w=A_1z^{b_3}+A_2z^{b_4}$$

This is a linear first order equation that you can lookup a general solution. For instance: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0103.pdf